# Upload Bitmap to Ruby Rails server

Tags: android, ruby-on-rails, ruby, json, bitmap

I need to send JSON like below:

```
story = {
            :story => {
              :uuid => "1234567890",
              :title => "Title",
              :subtitle => "Subtitle",
              :private => true,
              :bytes => [
                {
                  :uuid => "1234567890",
                  :timelineDate => "1970-01-01T00:00:00.000+00:00",
                  :caption => "Byte 1"
                  :photo => image
                }
    }
```

All work fine without image sending, but with image as Bitmap in JSON server return error

Request I send in this way:

```
  RestClient client = RestClient.getInstance(this, URL);
                        client.addHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");
                        client.addHeader("Authorization", "Token token=" token);    

//create JSON from Java objects
                        client.setJSONString(json);
                        client.execute(RestClient.RequestMethod.POST);
```

What type of image must to be to send it to Rails server?

Rails server want image like this:

```
 #<Rack::Test::UploadedFile:0x00000103ea6330
     @content_type="image/jpg",
     @original_filename="photo.jpg",
     @tempfile=
      #<File:/var/folders/1j/8b1khcf57fv1stf87gcylk8c0000gn/T/photo.jpg20140512-3303-1u2nkqo>
```

Comment: If you want to send image in JSON , you must convert image to Base64 string and then send will work

Answer (score 0):

Try this way

1) Convert Bitmap to Base64 String Like this

```
ByteArrayOutputStream byteArrayOutputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();  
bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, byteArrayOutputStream);
byte[] byteArray = byteArrayOutputStream .toByteArray();
```

to encode base64 from byte array use following method

```
String encoded = Base64.encodeToString(byteArray, Base64.DEFAULT);
```

2) set the value of photo in JSON

```
   json.put("photo",encoded);
```

Comment: if I send image as Base64 than got error on Rails: PaperClip::AdapterRegisrty::NoHandleError (No handler found for "lhLHLhLHLhLhLkhLhLhLkhLkhPioPHjkguyUV......")

lhLHLhLHLhLhLkhLhLhLkhLkhPioPHjkguyUV - it is String encoded

Comment: Ihor Kostenko@ any solution to this?